# iOS7 compiler won't recognize method call with message

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, methods, parameters

So this one has me stumped - probably something simple, but I'm clueless.

I'm defining a custom class, containing one method that receives one message (an integer).  When calling that method, the compiler refuses to recognize the message I'm trying to send along with the call.  ("No known class method for selector 'sendMessage:'.  Removing the message from both the call and the definition - i.e. removing the `:(int)mode` from the definition, and the `:1` from the call - allows it to compile fine (but then of course I lose the functionality).

I've tried defining it as an instance method, and as a class method - neither one works.

Many thanks in advance for your collective wisdom!

custom class "Communications.h":

```
@interface Communications : NSString

+(NSString*)sendMessage:(int)mode;

@end
```

Communications.m:

```
#import "Communications.h"

@interface Communications ()

@end

@implementation Communications

+(NSString*)sendMessage:(int)mode {

    // Do something important

}
```

ViewController.h:

```
#import "Communications.h"

- (void) tapPanic:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender;
```

ViewController.m:

```
- (void) tapPanic:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    [Animations animatePanic:self.view type:0];
    panicactive = 1;
    NSString* tmpResponse = [Communications sendMessage:1];
    UILabel* tmpServerResponsePanic = [self.view viewWithTag:10002];
    tmpServerResponsePanic.text = tmpResponse;
    [[self serverResponsePanic] setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

Comment: This probably will not fix the issue but why do you import "Communications.h" in your "ViewController.h"? Just import it into "ViewController.m".

Comment: BTW - why does `Communications` extend `NSString`? That's not good design since the `Communications` class isn't a specialized `NSString`. It should extend `NSObject` and probably have an `NSString` ivar if needed.

Comment: You're right, should import that in .m.  Poor structure.  re extension... Good point, but didn't make a difference... the method I'm calling returns NSString, and that was one of the changes I made while searching for an answer.  I'll change it back on principle - thanks for the poke. :)

Answer (score 0):

So, chalk it up to weirdness with Xcode... copy / pasting the contents of Communications .h and .m into new files, with a new class definition (Comms), did the trick.  I think the compiler got confused and was remembering an old definition of the method.